# In Redux-sagas how to cover lines like variable declaration and URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

How to get covered lines like variable declaration
the problem with this var URL declared line or statement or function. and I do not understand how to write a saga test case for the variable declared lines

```
export function* globalSearchAllAsync(action) {
    var url = "v1/globalSearch/globalSearchTextForAll?pageSize="+action.pageSize+"&recordFromIndex="+action.recordFromIndex;
    if(!checkEmptyOrNull(action.sortBy)){
        url = url + "&SortByProperty="+action.sortBy;
    }
    if(!checkEmptyOrNull(action.sortOrder)){
        url = url + "&sortOrder="+action.sortOrder;
    }
    try{
        const getData = yield NoccSearchServiceAxios.post(url, action.requestObj).then(result => {
            return result;
        });
        yield put(globalSearchAllSuccess(getData.data.response));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(fetchFailure(error.response.data.errorResponse.errorMessage, action.type))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please elaborate in your question what you mean by "covered lines" and "variable declaration"? It's not clear currently what problem you're trying to solve, or what's currently incorrect. Can you provide examples of what you want to happen, and demonstrate how your code currently doesn't work?

Comment: Are you trying to get test coverage of the function? If that's the case then the easiest way I've found to do that is using redux-saga-test-plan. Further; make the saga itself as simple as possible with very little logic in it other than to call out to other functions via yield call.

Comment: Read the testing doc https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing. Besides, you should provide minimal, complete code